# CSS: Absolute-positioned text won't center in div after adding text-overflow property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry I have to come back here again. But I added a `text-overflow: ellipses` property to my `TextCut` div because I need it truncated, but then it wouldn't center again. It sticks back to the left side instead of on the center where it should be. I tried solving it myself for an hour, but I am really bad at this I need help. I added my code again, thank you for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `margin: auto;` to `#TextCut`

```js
$(function(){
 $("#TextWrapper div:gt(0)").hide();
 setInterval(function(){
  var current = $('#TextWrapper div:visible');
  var next = current.next().length ? current.next() : $('#TextWrapper div:eq(0)');
  current.fadeOut(500);
  next.fadeIn(500);
 }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.Border {
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-flex;
 height: 110px;
}
#ImgAndText {
 text-align: center;
}
.Img {
 width: 75px;
 height:75px;
}
#TextWrapper, #TextWrapper1 {
 font-family: Helvetica;
 font-size: 13px;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
#TextWrapper div, #TextWrapper1 div {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
#TextCut {
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 text-align: center;
 width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Border">

 <div id="ImgAndText"> 
  <img src="#" class="Img">

  <div id="TextWrapper">
   <div>Text</div>
   <div id="TextCut">EvenMoreText</div>
  </div>
 </div> 
     
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that solved it! Can't believe it was just that simple, thank you!

Comment: glad i helped :D